# How to robocopy subfolders with content and files with a specific prefix

Tags: windows, robocopy

It is hard to believe but I seem to be not able to copy a folder with all its files (that begin with a certain character) and subfolders (beginning with the same character) to another folder in Windows 7. I used copy, xcopy and robocopy but all I do achieve is, that all files in the top level directory and all the subdirectories but without their content get copied. What am I doing wrong? I tried several ways, my last try was:

```
robocopy path\path\here x* path\path\there /E
```

I also tried

```
/COPYALL
/MIR
```

but with the same result.

Comment: Did you look at the robocopy help for info about the syntax? (`robocopy /?` or `help robocopy` from a command prompt will get you there.)

Comment: The issue is that the filter parameter of the copy command applies to the files, not to folders. If there is a limited depth to where these folders are, try using something like wildcards in the source/“here” parameter or the [`FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) looping construct to loop over folders which start with a particular character and then do a full copy of those.

Answer (score 29):

Your robocopy syntax is incorrect.  Is should be:

```
robocopy path\path\here path\path\there x* /E
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that is correct. But nevertheless it doesn't work. I noticed that "read only" (or "write protected, I am not sure because I use the German version) was partly marked in the properties. But changing this did not help as well.

Comment: Code:
`robocopy sourcefolder\ targetfolder\ u* /E`

-> This should copy all files and folders with a name starting with **u** to the target folder.

_Result:_ All files are copied correctly. But instead of copying only the folders that start with a **u** it copied ALL folders AND all of the without their content.

Comment: I realise it's been a few years, but did you manage to get this working, Daniel?

Comment: No and I neither received your comment @Hashim sorry

Comment: I know this is even older than it was the last time someone commented, but wouldn't the 'content' parameter be better suited as `\x*.*` or `x*.*` ?  @Largo, did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Thanks @k1dfr0std - unfortunately, I never solved it and even already forgot how I worked around that issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ROBOCOPY path\path\here path\path\there \*.* /E`

Comment: Please try to explain a bit more rather than giving just the answer

Comment: The OP wanted to copy all of the contents of any folders whose names started with a certain letter. Your command copies all contents of all folders, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @binki Hate to say this, but, fortunately for me that is the case. I came here because of the question "How to robocopy subfolders with content" and this nails it :)